# Flutter flutter_local_notifications do not show for Android on Release but shown in Debug

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, local

I utilize the `flutter_local_notifications` package (version ^16.3.1+1) in my Flutter application. However, upon publishing the app, I observed that local notifications were not functioning as expected on Android devices.

To address this issue, I employed a workaround involving the modification of the build.gradle file within the Android section of the project. Specifically, I disabled resource shrinking in the release build by adding `shrinkResources` false under the buildTypes section, as shown below:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        shrinkResources false // Added to enable notifications
    }
}
```

This adjustment proved effective in resolving the issue with local notifications. Nevertheless, I am in search of a more robust and perhaps more conventional solution. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could suggest a better fix for this problem.